# Javascript while loop strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, while-loop

The following code block should console log the array ('abc'), then enter the while loop once. In the while loop the value at the 1st index should be changed from 'a' to 'z'.
Finally the array will be returned.

However, it looks like the array is changed even before entering the loop as console.log(arr) yields ["z", "b", "c"] instead of ["a", "b", "c"].

```
function test(str){
   var arr = str.split('');
   var repeat = true;
   console.log(arr);
   while(repeat){
     repeat = false;
     arr[0] = 'z';
   }
   return arr;
}
console.log(test('abc'));
```

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome?  Its `console.log()` is asynchronous and often does weird things like this. It can happen in other browsers too, but Chrome is (in my experience) the worst offender.

Comment: I got `["a", "b", "c"]` and then `["z", "b", "c"]` with Google Chrome... seems ok on my side.

Comment: Please tell more about execution environment. Can't reproduce in Chrome and node.js (everywhere it works as supposed).

Comment: @freele: Try the snippets in my answer, in particular try the first snippet with the console **closed**, then open it and look at the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some console implementations (in particular Chrome's) show you a semi-live version of the object you logged, rather than a point-in-time copy of it. Then it gets frozen depending on what you do with it in the console (and at other times too; I've never quite understood the rules, and they vary from implementation to implementation.)

Example that replicates what you're seeing for me on Chrome — run it with the console **closed**, then open the console to view the result:

```js
function test(str){
  var arr = str.split('');
  var repeat = true;
  console.log(arr);
  while(repeat){
    repeat = false;
    arr[0] = 'z';
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(test('abc'));
```

```html
Run this with the console <strong>closed</strong>, then open it and look at the result.
```

Here's what I get when I do that, and then expand the two entries:

[image]

To be sure you're seeing a static copy instead, you could do this:

```
console.log(arr.join(", "));
```

...which logs a string containing the array entries, rather than the array object. Or you might use `JSON.stringify` rather than `join`. Or, for **me** (and your mileage may vary), having the console *open* when I run the first snippet above actually shows me static copies of the array (yes, really).

Example:

```js
function test(str){
  var arr = str.split('');
  var repeat = true;
  console.log(arr.join(", "));
  while(repeat){
    repeat = false;
    arr[0] = 'z';
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(test('abc').join(", "));
```

Or make a copy of the array and log the copy:

Example:

```js
function test(str){
  var arr = str.split('');
  var repeat = true;
  console.log(arr.slice(0));
  while(repeat){
    repeat = false;
    arr[0] = 'z';
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(test('abc').slice(0));
```

...but of course, if the array has objects in it, both arrays will refer to the same object, so you still might have dynamic issues.

Comment: I prefer copying the array: `console.log(arr.slice());`

Comment: @Oriol: Yeah, that's a good idea -- it's actually what I do (with an object graph) in one big app I work on.

Comment: I suppose it's not a semi-live copy, it's a pointer to an object, and it will log object content as it is in the moment of the actual render (i.e. when you open a console).

Comment: @freele: Basically, yeah; the "semi-live" bit is that individual bits are frozen as of when you show them. But for me the really weird thing is that when the console starts out closed, and I open it, I have `Array[3]` with an arrow next to it; clicking the arrow expands it and shows me the then-current info (and freezes it). But if I have the console open, I don't get that at all, I get `["a", "b", "c"]`. No `Array[3`], no arrow.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think it's kinda optimisation for browsing logging sites with closed console. But I agree it's weird you definitely expect synch log.

Answer (score 0):

As others said in chrome `console.log` function works asynchronously so sometime a change to the variable after using `console.log` will reflect in the log. I always print the object using

`console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));`

which will maintain the structure of the array or the object while printing.

Or copy the array
   `console.log(arr.slice(0));`